# Reading TTY does not work with cat

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, tty, cat

I have a `/dev/ttyUSB6` device (modem) which I was able writing to and reading from like so:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB6 speed 9600 line 0 -brkint -imaxbel -echo
echo "ATI" > /dev/ttyUSB6
cat /dev/ttyUSB6
```

`cat` would give me here the response to my sent string `ATI`.

However, after upgrading the kernel from 3.x to 5.x this does not work anymore. If I execute the commands above I get stuck on `cat` forever, it won't return a response. BUT if I open another terminal and run `cat /dev/ttyUSB6` on it and on another terminal I concurrently execute `echo "ATI > /dev/ttyUSB6` I get the response on the terminal where `cat` is running.

What am I missing here? Is there a kernel config parameter I missed to set/unset to get previous behaviour?

Comment: Try this `(stty speed 9600 line 0 -brkint -imaxbel -echo;  echo “ATI” > /dev/ttyUSB6; cat) </dev/ttyUSB6` ...

Comment: It works. Can you explain whats happening here? Why is behaviour from kernel 3.x to 5.x different. Did it change?

Comment: This keeps the tty device open for all the commands, rather than closing it and opening it between each command. The first open of a serial device will reset hardware to a default speed etc - maybe this default changed between kernels? Or maybe some other background process was keeping the device open?, or maybe the shell changed the way it opened devices? Could have been anything...